# Is it possible to read json in ADF and use it's keys within pipeline variables?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm gonna have to create set of pipelines based on json input file. This file contains configuration like paths, numbers etc. Each json input looks exactly the same (contains the same keys)

Is it possible to read json once and use it to define pipelines variables? Something like this:

1. read json -> returns dic
2. assign certain keys to pipeline variables like "VAR1 = dic.key1, VAR2 = dic.key2" etc.

My goal is to create single ARM template and just exchange the json files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I have found the soltion and I'm posting it here for futures.

"Lookup" activity does the job. In it's output we can access json body and call it like above.